# Number of occurrences in list of each element

Tags: algorithm, functional-programming

Given a list [x_1, x_2, ..., x_n]. I'm looking for an efficient implementation of a function that takes a list as input and outputs a list of the type [(x_1', n_1),...,(x_m', n_m)], where the x_i' are all distinct and n_i denotes the number of occurrences of x_i' in the input list.

There is a trivial way to do this in quadratic time without mutation. However, a typical simple method in an imperative language, where the x_i can be represented by small numerical values, is to use an array and do array[x_i]++ on each list element, then scan the array for nonzero entries and use that to construct the output list. The runtime is then linear (with bad performance for very small inputs).

There's an obvious better implementation without mutation. If the x_i have a well-defined ordering one can construct a binary search tree. Look up (x_i, k) in the tree. If it's not in the tree insert (x_i,1) otherwise remove (x_i,k) from the tree and insert (x_i,k+1). Finally, traverse the tree converting it into a list. Alternatively, sort the list and then traverse it in linear time. Both are O(nlog(n)).

Is there a better algorithm without mutation?

Comment: How about create a Map of all x_i and do an (insertWith (+) 1) and then convert the Map to list (in Haskell)?

Comment: @Priyatham: Great timing, I just added that as another possible solution. I'm wondering if this is optimal and if there is an asymptotically linear algorithm.

Comment: Without mutation, I don't think so. On the other hand this isn't bad either.

Comment: If you're only allowed to compare two elements (rather than index them), then the best thing you can do is sort the array and then compute the histogram in linear time; it's known that in this model, determining whether all elements are distinct requires time $\Omega(n\log n)$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following problem : Given a general list of comparable values, determine if all the elements are unique.

Assuming that all you know about the values is the comparison operation, you can use the [sorting lower bound proof](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spring14/cos340/sorting_lb.pdf) to show that this algorithm needs O(n log n) steps. Since your problem solves something stronger than this problem, it has O(n log n) as a lower bound as well.

Comment: Problem is, it's not completely apparent that without mutation the problem reduces to the case where the elements can only be compared. This is my key problem. I've looked briefly into the literature on persistent data structures, but didn't find a completely satisfactory answer.